# RestKit MongoDB location data mapping

Tags: ios, json, mongodb, restkit-0.20

I am having trouble understanding how to Map location Data stored in Mongo DB with RestKit.

Here is the data I will be mapping in JSON

```
{ "name" : "TestPoint2", "media_resource" : "tester", "added" : ISODate("2012-10-10T23:00:00Z"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  -33.1,  12.54 ] }, "comments" : [ ], "tags" : [ ]}
```

The main point I am struggling with is mapping the "coordinates" of "loc"

Comment: I haven't tried anything for it yet as I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do it.

I would be looking to access them from object.lat object.long but any way possible wouldn't matter to me

Comment: The problem is that they are in an array, so you'll find it very difficult to map them straight out into variables. To map out of the array and into objects you'd use a nil key path, but the order will still be an issue. Any chance you can get the JSON changed?

Comment: I don't thinks as I am using MongoDB's built in geospatial-indexes and they need to be represented as they are now

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I'd treat the coordinates as they are represented in the JSON and store them as numbers in an array. If your object / entity has an array property / transformable attribute then you can just map the `coordinates` into that wholesale. You can then add accessor methods / transient attribute(s) which access that coordinate information and provide a nicer interface to get the lat/long than indexing into an array.